# Declaration of char pointer array without knowing the size at programm start

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, size

I have char* Array in a struct that strores song titles. Depending an the album the array size may vary. To be "safe" i defined the array with the size of 99. The code example below shows my problem
Is there a better way (i am sure there is) to solve the array size problem? Somehow creating the array after knowing the exact size of the array?
Thank you.

```
    struct AudioObject{
    int count;
    const char* band;
    const char * titles[99];
};
void fillStruct(AudioObject *a);
void printStruct(AudioObject * a);
void main(void){
    AudioObject aO;
    fillStruct(&aO);
    printStruct(&aO);
} 
void fillStruct(AudioObject *a){ 
    a->count=3; 
    a->band="Iron Maiden";
    const char *arr[3]={"The Wicker Man","Ghost of the Navigator","Brave New World"}; // example input
    for(int i=0;i<a->count;i++){
        a->titles[i]=arr[i];
    }  
}
void printStruct(AudioObject * a){
    printf("Interpret: %s\n",a->band);
    printf("Tracks: %d\n",a->count);
    for(int i=0;i<a->count;i++){
        printf("Title: %s\n",a->titles[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `char **` and allocate the memory run time.

Comment: Let him who have understanding reckon the size of the array... :)

Answer (score 0):

In case this needs to be read-only, you should let `titles` be a `const char**` (or pedantically, `const char*const *const`) pointing to a separate array such as:

```
const char* IRON_MAIDEN_TITLES[] = { "...", };
```

If you do that, you probably wish to store the size of each such title array too, in a separate variable in the struct.

Another option is to skip `const` and allocate anything dynamically. You can for example make the last member of the struct a *flexible array member*:

```
 struct AudioObject{
    int count;
    char* band;
    char * titles[];
};
```

Then when you know the size, you allocate the whole object like this:

```
size_t number_of_titles = 666;
AudioObject* ao = malloc(sizeof *ao + sizeof(const char* [number_of_titles]));
```

and then `strcpy (ao->titles[0], "something");`

Comment: I googled a lot to find an example for char**. To be honest I didn't find much about it. Could you give me an example how to access this array? const char ** titles[]; in the struct. but how do I fill this array?strcpy(a->ar[i],arr[i]);  dows not work